# Print Preview without opening Excel application [VB.net]

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

In VB.net Can I Print Preview without show Excel application? I have looked for this in many places and haven't found the answer.

Now I use this method.

```
Dim XSh As Object = CreateObject("excel.application")
XSh.workbooks.open("D:\WP\formPrint.xlsx")
XSh.visible = True

For i As Integer = 0 To count

    XSh.worksheets(1).range("A21").value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
    XSh.worksheets(1).range("A22").value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
    XSh.worksheets(1).range("A23").value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
    XSh.worksheets(1).range("A24").value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value

    XSh.Sheets.PrintPreview()
    XSh.Sheets.PrintOut()

Next i

XSh.workbooks(1).close(SaveChanges:=False)
XSh.application.Quit
```

and I've tried to change

```
XSh.visible = False
```

It's don't show any things. I want to show just Print Preview don't show excel application file. How Can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The Print Preview is part of the Excel Application, so it will only show when you set `XsH.visible = true` You can also only set it to true right before you show the Print Preview and set it back to false when it's printed.

```
Dim XSh As Object = CreateObject("excel.application")
XSh.workbooks.open("D:\WP\formPrint.xlsx")
XSh.visible = False

For i As Integer = 0 To count

    XSh.worksheets(1).range("A21").value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
    XSh.worksheets(1).range("A22").value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
    XSh.worksheets(1).range("A23").value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
    XSh.worksheets(1).range("A24").value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value

    XSh.visible = True
    XSh.Sheets.PrintPreview()
    XSh.Sheets.PrintOut()
    XSh.visible = False

Next i

XSh.workbooks(1).close(SaveChanges:=False)
XSh.application.Quit
```